# random particles on a grid: Effect of increasing density on distance between them

Tags: particle-physics, geometry, distance

[image]

Say I have two boxes which both contain, say, 25 red particles (as shown in picture). These particles are randomly placed in a 2d grid, and in one the total area $A_{1}=20000$ and the other has area $A_{2}=10000$.

If the average distance between any two particles before was $d_{1}$, what is the average (expected) distance between any two particles after, $d_{2}$?

I have worked it out as:

Since we have vertically compressed the box by factor 0.5:
[image]

Then we get a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{1.25}}{\sqrt{2}}$ = 0.7905.... of the distance $d_{1}$. However, I am not sure if this is correct because surely the particles would be 
closer together in the x-direction as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a box of area $A$ containing $N$ particles then the average area per particle, $a$, is:

$$ a = \frac{A}{N} \tag{1} $$

If the particles aren't arranged in any special way we expect the environment of any particular particle to be symmetric on average, so let's suppose that each particle on average occupies a circle of radius $r$, then the area of each particle's circle is $a = \pi r^2$. Putting this expression for $a$ in equation (1) we get:

$$ \pi r^2 = \frac{A}{N} $$

or with a quick rearrangement:

$$ r = \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi N}} $$

The average separation, call this $d$, will be the distance between the centres of the circles so $d = 2r$ and therefore:

$$ d = 2\sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi N}} $$

This is all rather approximate, but the key point is that if the number of particles is constant, as in your case, the important relationship is:

$$ d \propto \sqrt{A} $$